# Dynamically generated ajax data Post from jQuery to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table that generating dynamic raw's, I need to send through ajax post to receive from PHP. Below I have given all my selected codes, this is not working.

In console showing as

> PHP ERROR: Undefined index all_ch_no, all_yd_stock_no, all_comments

HTML FORM, below table rows are dynamically generated through ajax, if I place static table data, then it's working! How can I solve?

```
<form method="post" id="customer_do_add">
   <input type="text" id="phone_no" name="phone_no">

    <table class="table" id="group_cars">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20%;">Chassis No</th>
                <th style="width: 15%;">Yard Stock No</th>
                <th style="width: 50%;">Comments</th>
                <th style="width: 15%;">Remove</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="waz" value="DD51T-224534" name="all_ch_no[]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="waz"  value="77832" name="all_yd_stock_no[]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="waz"  value="Test3" name="all_comments[]"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="waz" value="DD51T-45354" name="all_ch_no[]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="waz"  value="123123" name="all_yd_stock_no[]"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="waz"  value="Test" name="all_comments[]"></td>
            </tr> 
            ...
        </thead>
    </table>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
  $('#customer_do_add').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var val = $('#customer_do_add').serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url: "auction/customer_do_add/",
                data:val,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                    result = $.parseJSON(responseText);
                }
            });
            return false;
    });
```

PHP

```
public function customer_do_add(){
            print_r($_POST); 
            exit;
}
```

Printing Only Phone number, Arrays are not printing

```
Array
(
    [phone_no] => 123456
)
```

Comment: Please confirm whether "submit" event is triggered or not.

Comment: its triggered, even If I send a variable, its passing, only problem on passing an array

Comment: What do you mean by "only problem on passing an array"?

Comment: try passing some index in the array like all_ch_no[0]

Comment: not  print_r($_POST['all_ch_no']); in console

Comment: @Aju John, I did, not working

Comment: Just try printing $_POST. What is the result?

Comment: Nothing print, PHP error Undefined index all_ch_no, all_yd_stock_no, all_comments

Comment: ajaxSubmit isn't a core jquery function, I believe. Something like this : http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ if you are using a "jquery.form.js" file than it's working fine.

Comment: I already mentioned in the question that Im using jquery form

Comment: @Wazan: please use only print_r($_POST); exit; in  your PHP function. What is the result now?

Comment: Array
(
    [phone_no] => 052456789
    [all_ch_no] => 
    [all_yd_stock] => 
    [all_comments] => 
)

Comment: @Wazan: Can you try giving type="text" to the inputs?

Comment: If you are using Google Chrome then press F12, go to the Network tab, click on the `auction/customer_do_add` URL, click on the Headers tab, and scroll down to Form Data. Does it display the POST variables which you are expecting?

Comment: @Wazan: try with normal ajax request, so that it will be easy to debug.

Comment: @AjuJohn Now edited the quetion with normal Jquery

Comment: How about `$('#customer_do_add').serialize()` instead of `$('#customer_do_add').serializeArray();`?

Comment: @Gogol Same results

Answer (score 0):

Send data params in Jquery call then only you can receive post

```
 $('#customer_do_add').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $('#customer_do_add').serializeArray();
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            url: "auction/customer_do_add/",
            data: val,
            success: function (responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                result = $.parseJSON(responseText);
            }
        });
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Array ( [phone_no] => 052456789 [all_ch_no] => [all_yd_stock] => [all_comments] => )  Printing Like this only

Answer (score 0):

Your $_POST is empty because jQuery.ajax() will pass data as GET data (it's being appended to the url). Setting the method arg to post will fix this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/auction/customer_do_add/",
    data: val,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
});
```

You could also use [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for a simplified syntax;

```
$.post({
    url: "/auction/customer_do_add/",
    data: val,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the developer console? MonkeyZeus gave you instructions for that in the comments on your main post.